# how to permanently disable wifi power management for linux mint 18?

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, linux-mint, power-management

I have upgraded from mint 17.3 to mint 18, and now I experience irritating wifi problems, which are (probably) connected to the power management.

Before the upgrade, I had set it off in the `/etc/pm/power.d/wireless` file (sudo chmod +x), like:

```
#!/bin/sh
/sbin/iwconfig wlan0 power off
```

And it just worked.

Now, Mint 18 ignores these settings. Also, the `wlan0` was changed to `wlp2s0`.

But the worst part is, even if I set the power management off in the console, I can still feel the connection is disgustingly slow, and there are constant gaps. The only way to fix that is to reset wifi... every few minutes.

This is the `iwconfig` output, where the power management is clearly off, but I have no internet conection:

```
$ iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.

enp3s0    no wireless extensions.

wlp2s0    IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"okolig"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.457 GHz  Access Point: 6C:19:8F:8D:ED:ED   
          Bit Rate=52 Mb/s   Tx-Power=16 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=56/70  Signal level=-54 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:65   Missed beacon:0
```

Any help? If this problem persists, I will have to change the distro after 2 years, because working with a starving wifi card is kind of complicated.

Comment: Although you seem to have solved your problem, the renaming of `wlan0` to `wlp2s0` is a result of enabling [Predictable Network Interface Names](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/PredictableNetworkInterfaceNames/) in the kernel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems to be fixed after reinstalling the system. During installation, pick an option for installing 3rd party drivers and proprietary software.